# Good programming style with optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

I want to read an enum parameter from NSUserdefaults. In case there is nothing set in Userdefaults I want it to default to a certain value. Is there a better way (more elegant) to do this than what I did here with the "if let" statement? And as this is a Singleton I want to access the value in other parts of my code using

`if GameState.learnLevel == Level.low {..}`

how would I do that?

```
class GameState {

var learnLevel:Level
enum Level:Int {
   case low = 1,medium,high
}

class var sharedInstance: GameState {
    return _SomeManagerSharedInstance
}

init(){

    // load games state
    let learnLevel = Level(rawValue: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("learnLevel"))

    if let learnLevel1 = learnLevel {self.learnLevel = learnLevel1} else {self.learnLevel = Level.low}

}
```

Comment: Other than putting in the correct line breaks then that seems ok. You're taking a value from NSUserDefaults which may not be there and setting a required property from it. Without the line breaks though it makes it hard to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nil` coalescing [operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123) `??`:

```
    let learnLevel = Level(rawValue: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("learnLevel"))        
    self.learnLevel = learnLevel ?? Level.low
```